# Statistics: Relationship between process capability and mean

Tags: normal-distribution

A company produces one-kilogram sugar packets. The specifications on the net content are 1000 ≠ 5 grams. Assuming that the net content follows normal distribution with mean weight as 1005 grams and the process capability equal to 30 grams, find out the proportion of packets that have weight less than lower specification limit. What should be the mean if this proportion is to be reduced to 0.01?

I have no idea what is the relation between process capability and mean. How do I solve it?

Comment: what do you mean by 1000 ≠ 5 grams ?

Comment: I believe it's +/- like 995/1005.....

Comment: then it would have a mean weight of 1000 grams, not 1005 grams

Comment: but the mean weight is given as 1005?

Comment: exactly, so something must be wrong with your statement of the problem

Comment: I don't know. It's given that way as I wrote. Can you just tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The [process capability](http://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmc/section1/pmc16.htm) will give you the $\sigma$ of the process:

Rewriting $$C_p = \frac{USL-LSL}{6\sigma}$$ we get 
$$
\sigma = \frac{USL-LSL}{6C_p} = \frac{1005-995}{6(30)} = \frac{1}{18}
$$
So you know that the process has a normal distribution with $\mu = 1005,$ and $\sigma=1/18$. Then it's just calculating the probability that $x<=995$ for this distribution.

Part 1. You can integrate the weight $x$ using the [PDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) of the normal distribution over $[0, 995]$ or simply use the [CDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) of the normal distribution to get the answer. 
$$
CDF(x=995) = \frac{1}{2}\left[ 1+\text{erf}\left(\frac{x-\mu}{\sqrt{2\sigma^2}}\right)\right]
$$
You should be able to find a tabulated table for the error function $\text{erf}$ or use a calculator.

Part 2. Set $CDF(x=995)= 0.01$, and solve for $\mu$.

Comment: Thanks for the great job... if you don't mind can you help me with the rest as well? Or maybe a link where I can read the specific part?

Comment: I edited the solution and added the rest. A note about your Process Capability value of 30. It seems to be wrong, [see this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_capability_index) for approximate value ranges. Could it possibly be 0.3?

Comment: no idea... I wrote the question as I got it....

Comment: In the question it says process capability is 30... shouldn't it be `6σ = 30`? So that `σ = 5`